# How to open Files with Python script directly in Windows Explorer

Tags: python, pdf, microsoft-file-explorer

so my Question is if there is a method which i can use, where i can directly open Multiple Files with my Python script.

**Example Use Case:**

1. I downloaded multiple PDFs and i see them all in my download folder.
2. Now i select them all and right-click -> open with -> mypythonscript (then the script merges them together for example).
3. This would allow my python script to be directly started from the windows explorer.
   Is there a way to to that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes but how would I implement this whole idea. What can I search for in Google or YouTube ? Thank you